# i want to make selection from database for a given date interval

Tags: php, codeigniter

i want to make selection from database for a given date interval

> $last= date("Y-m-t", strtotime("0 month") );
>   $start= date("Y-m-1",
>   strtotime("0 month") );

i want to make selection for values between **$start** and **$last**, and here is my controller

> $incomes=$this->select_model->get_income(array('i.date_of_income'=>$start, 
>    'i.date_of_income'=>$last));

and here is my model:-

> function get_income($where=FALSE){
>   $this->db->select('*');
>   $this->db->from('unit u');
>   $this->db->join('income i','u.registration_number=i.registration_number','left');
>   if($where){
>   $this->db->where($where);
>   }
>   $query = $this->db->get();
>    return $query->result_array();
>   }

Comment: You have oposite operator when comparing `$last`

Comment: Could you please post the database table structure with sample data, if possible, please provide SQL fiddle link for the accurate solution.

Answer (score 1):

For interval time you can use `BETWEEN` mysql keyword.

```
$incomes=$this->select_model->get_income("i.date_of_income BETWEEN '" . $start . "' AND '" . $last . "'");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use it.
Controller Query

```
$incomes=$this->select_model->get_income($start,$last);
```

Model Query

```
function get_income($start=null,$last = null){
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('unit u');
$this->db->join('income i','u.registration_number=i.registration_number','left');
if(!empey($start) && !empey($last){
$this->db->where('i.date_of_income >=', $first_date);
$this->db->where('i.date_of_income <=', $second_date);
}

$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result_array();
}
```

OR

You can change only controller

```
$incomes = $this->select_model->get_income("i.date_of_income BETWEEN '{$start}' AND '{$last}'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Call the function like this

$incomes=$this->select_model->get_income('i.date_of_income BETWEEN $start AND $last');

Comment: check your start and end date is printing currect